# How to align this div?

Tags: html, css

How to align this green div with the first and last li of the nav???
I'm trying to resize the main with the nav elements but it doesn't work

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.homepage {
    border: rgb(241, 16, 16) 1px solid;
    height: 800px;
}
.navbar {
    border: rgb(255, 255, 255) 1px solid;
}
.nav-elements {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
main {
    border: springgreen 1px solid;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="homepage">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav-elements">
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>safsa</main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to align this green div with the first and last li of the nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex` for the homepage element, `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: center`, remove the margin from the `main` element and set its width to 80%. Set your width (100%) and height for nav-bar and width (100%) for homepage. I also added a ***reset*** for **padding**, **margin** and **box-sizing** as well.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    .homepage {
        border: rgb(241, 16, 16) 1px solid;
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .navbar {
        border: rgb(255, 255, 255) 1px solid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .nav-elements {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding-top: 14px;
    }
    main {
        border: springgreen 1px solid;
        height: 500px;    
        width: 80%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav-elements">
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>safsa</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this styling for your main:

Using `left: 15%` and `right: 12%` will add a margin relative to the current width.

```
main {
    border: springgreen 1px solid;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 12%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

So your code would be like this:

```css
body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    .homepage {
        border: rgb(241, 16, 16) 1px solid;
        height: 800px;
    }
    .navbar {
        border: rgb(255, 255, 255) 1px solid;
    }
    .nav-elements {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    main {
        border: springgreen 1px solid;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 12%;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav-elements">
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>safsa</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer but what I want to do it is to fit the green div with the first element "123" and the last one, like with that margin in the nav-elements.

Comment: So aligning the green div with the first and last 123s?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for.